# JDBCTemplate setQueryTimeout specific for each query i.e, Query Level

Tags: spring, jdbc

I need to set query timeout for various ranges of queries depending on the data they pull. ie, each query will have their own timeout time.

say for instance, query A - > 10 MINUTES
                  query B - > 5 MINUTES

Now how do I set these different timings using the getJDBCTemplate(). When I try the below code snippet, the timeout is overidden and both the queries are timing out on the same time irrespective of the setting!

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
       getJdbcTemplate().setQueryTimeout(5);
       List t = getJdbcTemplate()
                   .query("select top 10000 * from ABC",new RowMapper<T>(){
                   ..
       });

Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
       getJdbcTemplate().setQueryTimeout(10);
       List t = getJdbcTemplate()
        .query("select top 30000 * from XYZ",new RowMapper<T>() {
                        ..
       });
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

In the above context, both the queries are timing out at 5th min or 10th min. Is there a way to set it up based on the query ? please suggest!

**[UPDATE]**

```
<bean id="dSource" class="com.xyz.DSource" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

public abstract class AbstractData  {
    private DSource dSource;
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(){

        ApplicationContext Ctx = ContextUtils.getApplicationContext(); 
        dSource = (DSource)Ctx.getBean("dSource");
        return dSource.getJDBCTemplate();
         }
}

public class DSource extends JdbcDaoSupport{
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(){
        return getJdbcTemplate();
    }
}

public Class Dao extends AbstractData{
     public void callQuery(){
        [AS already posted, t1 and t2 are 2 threads for 2 diff methods/queries using 
         getJDBCTemplate Of abstract classs]

       Thread 1 
       Thread 2
     }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The timeout is overridden probably because because your JdbcTemplate is singleton(please add its configuration). To achieve what you want you need dedicated JdbcTemplate for every class(or method).

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
       JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
       template.setQueryTimeout(5);
       List t = template
                   .query("select top 10000 * from ABC",new RowMapper<T>(){
                   ..
       });
```

I don't think this is ideal. Probably better solution will be to use pure jdbc and set the timeout directly to the prpared statement

```
    Connection con = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()
    preparedstatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedstatement.setQueryTimeout(theTimeout);
```

You have t check if Spring will close the statement and connection in this case or you will need to handle this yourself.

Comment: Thanks Evgeni, you mean to say,    `Connection con = getJDBCTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection()` right?    I tried that, but for some reasons it taking a bit more time to close the connection in connection pool when the time-out exception is thrown. BTW, am closing the connection manually in the finally block.    Please suggest!

Comment: This means that spring cant close the connection and you have to close it yourself as you already do in the finally block. Yes getJDBCTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection() is OK, but in this case since you will not use the jdbcTeamplate, for this queries you can just inject the datasource, get the connection from it and then close the connection in the finally.

Comment: Yeah, its a better option to use the datasource. I'm planning to get the bean it via applicationcontext and use it.    `ApplicationContext appCtx = ContextUtils.getApplicationContext();     
DataSource dSource= (DataSource)appCtx.getBean("dSource");`    This should work out right?

Comment: Yes. Also if the the class where you will use the datasource is spring bean you can inject the datasource.

Comment: Nope thats a abstract class and not a spring bean. So am going about using the app context!

Answer (score 1):

Spring JdbcTemplate has method variants that accept CallableStatementCreator / PreparedStatementCreator objects as a parameter. You can use these objects to create and configure statements.

For example, you can write implementation of CallableStatementCreator to support query-level timeout as follows:

```
public class TimeoutCallableStatementCreator implements CallableStatementCreator {

    private final String callString;
    private final int timeout;

    public TimeoutCallableStatementCreator(String callString, int timeout) {
        Assert.notNull(callString, "Call string must not be null");
        this.callString = callString;
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    @Override
    public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall(this.callString);
        stmt.setQueryTimeout(timeout);
        return stmt;
    }
}
```

Note: If you set timeout for JdbcTemplate, it overrides timeout set through CallableStatementCreator / PreparedStatementCreator.